# Using distcp to copy to Azure ADLS Gen1 fails with 403

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake, distcp

I am trying to copy to Azure Data Lake Storage (ADLS) Gen1, while authenticating using OAuth2.

I am getting the following error:

> com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLException: Error getting info for file /myContainer
>       Operation GETFILESTATUS failed with HTTP403 : null

Here's how my `distcp` looks like

```
hadoop distcp 
    -Dfs.adl.oauth2.access.token.provider.type=ClientCredential 
    -Dfs.adl.oauth2.client.id=<client_id>
    -Dfs.adl.oauth2.credential=<key>
    -Dfs.adl.oauth2.refresh.url=https://login.microsoftonline.com/*****/oauth2/token 
hdfs:///path/to/file 
adl://adlsgen1.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer
```

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Could you please how you configure ACL for the service principal : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-service-to-service-authenticate-using-active-directory

Comment: I must be missing something since I don't have that option in the menu. I have created a storage account of kind "Storage (general purpose v1)". Also have another one that is gen2.
I also enabled hierarchical namespace while creating it, although it doesn't have that lightning icon as in the link you sent, it is simply a storage account. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you please tell me which service you use?[Azure blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction)  [Azure Data lake gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction) or [Azure data lake gen1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-overview)?

Comment: OK - realized my mistakte. 
I Was using ADLS gen2 with the uri scheme of adl:// while it requires abfs://. 
Once I created a ADLS Gen1 storage, it worked. 
However, using abfs:// for ADLS Gen2 won't work as it seems this filesystem isn't supported in our Hadoop version (2.6.x). Is there an easy way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Azure AD to access Azure data lake gen2 with a service principal, we need to [configure RABC role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad#built-in-rbac-roles-for-blobs-and-queues) for the service principal.

For example

1. Create a service principal and assign `Storage Blob Data Owner` to the sp.(I use Azure CLI).

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp" --role "Storage Blob Data Owner"\
    --scopes /subscriptions/{SubID}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroup1} \
    /subscriptions/{SubID}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroup2}
```

2. configure

```
hadoop distcp 
    -D fs.azure.account.auth.type=OAuth 
    -D fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type=org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider
    -D fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint=[token endpoint],
    -D fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id=[Application client ID],
    -D fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret=[client secret]
hdfs:///path/to/file 
abfs://container1@abfswales1.dfs.core.windows.net/
```

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure/abfs.html#OAuth_2.0_Client_Credentials) and the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-cli)

Comment: putting secrets on the command line will make it visible to anyone on the host who can run the ps command. dont do it on a shared system.